# Crontab opens as blank page, cannot save

Tags: gedit, cron

I am really not familiar with linux, and only started using it recently, so be patient with me. 
I am trying to control a camera on regular intervals through a script that is called upon in the crontab.
When I start up the computer, I can open crontab, edit and save, and everything is executed correctly. However, I can never open crontab a second time, unless I restart the computer first. If I type crontab -e, I get a blank page, located in the /tmp directory. I can enter my commands in there, but cannot save it.

I don't know if this is relevant, but when I try sudo crontab -e, I get something like "no cron installed for root".

Any help is really appreciated!

Sarah

[edit] Problem solved: the problem was the editor (gedit), when using nano as editor, I can access crontab, edit and save without problems!

Comment: welcome to askubuntu! please post your solution as an answer below - it's okay to answer your own questions here.

Comment: Problem solved: the problem was the editor (gedit), when using nano as editor, I can access crontab, edit and save without problems!

Answer (score 0):

The `crontab -e` command will check the environment variables `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL` for an override of the default text editor, so...
Two of the many other possible ways can be applied:

**1. Either**: Run `select-editor` command on  terminal (you can get a terminal by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+T`) as below

```
$ select-editor 

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/ed
  2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  3. /usr/bin/vim.basic
  4. /usr/bin/vim.tiny

Choose 1-4 [2]:
```

The default here is chosen as `2` mentioned in the square bracket. Your answer will take the default to run with `crontab -e` when run independently.

**2. OR**: (This is my personal fav.) Choose one of the following to override default editor:

```
$ export EDITOR=nano
```

or

```
$ export VISUAL=nano
```

Of course, this `#2` choice you can make permanent by putting it on your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.